# Mysql Query Browser - Setting up and adding connection on it

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have some databases (SQL), My tech guy connected those to the Mysql query browser. Extension of those databases are.MYI and.MYD. For some reason, I had to format my laptop, but fortunately, I have the data in my external hard drive and I have Mysql Query browser and its related files (like Instance config and Server 5.5), how do I connect these databases to MySQL query browser. So, once they are connected, I can directly search through commands. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You must have absolutely the same MySQL version. Create temporary database and empty tables with absolutely the same structures. Stop MySQL. Replace table files. Start MySQL. Try to access the data. But I recommend that you call a specialist.

Comment: Thank you sir, But I am newbie. But, I  have all the data( data is not deleted) and also I have the same version of Mysql query browser. I just somehow need to attach / connect them as Schemata so that my query's can be executed. Thanks!

Comment: I think what i mean is importing / adding the database to mysql query browser.

Comment: Firstly you must attach your data files to MySQL server. This task is not related to query browser (which is client software simply, and which can access the data which is correctly stored/maintained by MySQL server). And this task (attaching detached tables files) is not simple and easily performed one.

Comment: Yes sir, thats what my query is, that I am not able to attach data files to Mysql browser. I'm a newbie, please understand. Thanks again!

Comment: Forget about Query browser. Only command-line client must be used for this operation.

Comment: https://www.javaguicodexample.com/mysqlinstallusewinguitools_files/mysqlinstallguitool044.jpg

Sir, like in the image in this link, See under schemata they have multiple Databases, similarly I want my databases to be listed there and I can execute my query. Also, i have followed all the steps mentioned in (https://www.javaguicodexample.com/mysqlinstallusewinguitools.html), but still its not working, so asking for help. Thanks again!

Comment: You follow the steps applied when all data is correctly registered and correctly accessed. This is not true for your data, so these steps cannot help you. You must perform complex recovering process. This process is not simple and may (moreover, must) vary depends on your particular system state. So I recommend you to call a specialist strongly - the man who performs this recovery must have enough knowledge about MySQL server. Without this you may even break something else in your system.

Comment: Sir, i have the data, I haven't LOST it. I don't want to recover it. I just want the database files under schemata

Comment: You LOOSE it. You have files which contains your data, but you need to recover them as a database connected to server. Your situation looks like you have an archive with your files but have no dearchivator - files are not lost but are not accessible.